# How can I turn off the Wii U Gamepad without turning off the console?

Tags: wii-u

I usually leave my Wii U charging some devices and installing some apps/games, while this is being done, I want to completely turn off the gamepad.

How can I turn off the gamepad and leave the console turned on?

(if no native solutions exist, Homebrew is also an option)

Comment: When playing through Breath of the Wild; I literally put post-it notes over the Wii U screen so that the light coming from it wasn't distracting.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to waste power on the gamepad when is literally doing anything (stuff like the Downloader and FTP Servers via Homebrew don't show anything interesting).

Comment: Not sure about charging devices, but I’m pretty sure that the Wii U will still download stuff in sleep mode.